# RewriteRule for handling multiple domains within one single app?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, virtualhost

Say I have an **app** at `example.com.`

One **customer** migth have it's content in `example.com/customer/hisname/`.

Well, I would like to make possible that the customer ***assigns*** a domain for his content, say `hisname.com`, so this (hisdomain.com) renders `example.com/customer/hisname/`.

To do that I have created two virtual hosts, both having the root directory in the same place, and I have written a .htaccess file in order to filter the http_host and if not example.com then rewrite in such manner that it passes the request to example.com/customer/hisname/.

Still, this approach doesn't work while I do not get the /customer/hisname/ part in URI.
If I go to hisname.com/list/ in the example.com/index.php, where I would need to have both /list/ and (as a prefix) /customer/hisname/, I only get, as you might expect just /list/.

So, what would be the right approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can create [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/), you should set the proper document root instead of using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
<VirtualHost w.x.y.z:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@hisname.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/www/customer/hisname
    ServerName hisname.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

If this is not possible, you can extract the `host` part and do an internal rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?prefix=customer/%1&request=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I just tried again the first approach you suggested.

so, I have a .htaccess that looks like this:

   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule (.*) index.php

And 2 virtual host:
   One has DocumentRoot "D:/XAMPP Servers/xampp/htdocs/domains_app/customer/"
   The other has DocumentRoot "D:/XAMPP Servers/xampp/htdocs/domains_app/"

While second one works just fine, the second one brings a 500 error (Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects...).

Comment: @Michael `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is always true, because of the `OR`. Please see updated answer.

Comment: I would like to make the first approach working while I can create virtual hosts, but I have removed that logical operator and I still get the 500 error. I don't know where is that coming from..

Comment: The problem seems to be with the DocumentRoot. If I set it to [..]domains_app/customer/ it triggers the 500 error. If i remove /customer/ it works. Now, of course, the customer folder does not exist - it would be interpreted by a dispatcher and finally a controller would get in stage..

Comment: If I set the same Document root for both vhosts then the htaccess kind of does the job. Do you have any additional hints/refs regarding the method which doesn't imply the use of RewriteRule? I might not get it right.. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael Maybe I misunderstood your application. If you set a different DocumentRoot, you must duplicate the application's PHP files as well. If this is the same for both domains, then the htaccess approach would be the corrent approach. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

use the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and load a different view depending on the host requested. Make sure you handle all subhosts needed and have a default page as well