# Domain handling with a controller

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im running an MVC based application on my mainsite, I have 2 other domains (for the sake of an example, www.a.com & www.b.com)

I'd like to be able to handle all a.com's requests with mainsite.com/a/ and similarly b.com with mainsite.com/b/

However I do not want the url to be redirected/changed in the browser.

I've been trying with mod_rewrite, however it seems to be clashing with my existing .htaccess rules set for mainsite.com

[this is my existing .htaccess](http://pastebin.com/PYPVUDr1)

Could anyone please suggest the best way to do this?

Comment: Which rules have you tried? And how do these rules clash with the existing .htaccess?

Comment: Hi @OlafDietsche - I actually tried the way you suggested in one of your earlier answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729641/rewriterule-for-handling-multiple-domains-within-one-single-app)

But I dont have a 'real' document root , its a controller served by php

Comment: Ok, and what do you mean with clash? Do you get a 500 server error or any other error?

Comment: Its a 404 as far as i can tell. But the root controller gives a 500 error

Comment: When it is a 500 error, there is an error in the .htaccess. 404 could mean, the rules don't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the existing .htaccess, I don't see any rules redirecting the domains `a.com` or `b.com`. To do that is pretty straightforward, though.

A condition for selecting the proper host `www.a.com` or `a.com`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?a\.com$
```

prevent an endless loop

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a/
```

and do the actual rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^ /a%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

As long as you don't use the [`R`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag, the URL shouldn't change in the browser.

The rule for host `b.com` is analogous.

*Update:*

Since you already have a very large .htaccess file, the performance impact shouldn't matter too much. If you want to know for sure, there's no substitute for measuring.

If you want to reduce the performance hit nevertheless, you have two options

- Move the directives in the .htaccess file to your main config or virtual config file, see [When (not) to use .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when) for an explanation.
- Do some custom rewriting with PHP in your front controller. This depends on the framework or routing mechanism you use, of course.

Comment: Thanks this worked, but is this the best way to do what im trying to do? performance wise?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the main config. 

Is Rewriting with PHP better than using the mod_rewrite? by better im only looking at speed here

Comment: I never measured one against the other, so I cannot tell. But since you already use a PHP controller, it *might* be cheaper to just use this one system instead of two. But to be really sure, you must implement both and do a performance test.

Comment: If you have access to the main config, it is definitely better to move the .htaccess directives to the main config. As the link describes, the .htaccess is parsed with every request, whereas the main config is parsed only once at startup.

Comment: Ok, to be honest, I dont know how to do a performance test for this. Are they any ways or tools for it?

Once again, thankyou so much for all your help

Comment: I am not an expert either. You might look into [ab - Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/ab.html). [Wikipedia - Web server benchmarking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_benchmarking) lists also some tools. You can install a webserver on your local machine, to remove the network latency impact.